# Node streaming adding header sends the file incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have kind of a odd bug. if i do the following:

```
res.header('content-disposition', 'filename=' + mediaObject.file.originalname);
```

i am able to download the file.

However as soon as i add an additional line to the header the file downloads incorrectly for instance:

```
res.header('content-disposition', 'filename=' + mediaObject.file.originalname,"Content-Length: " + mediaObject.file.size);
```

The values of the `mediaObject`:

```
File:

buffer: null
encoding: 7bit
extension: mp4
fieldname: file
mimetype: video/mp4
name: test1434922812720.mp4
originalname: test.mp4
path: uploads/test1434922812720.mp4
size: 22179964
truncated: false
```

So my question is what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are not properly using the `res.header` method since you are trying to set two key/value pairs in the same call.

The correct prototype of the `header` method is [`res.header(field [, value])`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set).

I would rather suggest using [`res.download`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.download) which is probably more indicated for what you are trying to achieve and takes care of setting the appropriate headers for you.

Comment: what if im trying to stream

Comment: That was not mentioned in your question. For streaming purposes, I would create a read stream (using fs.createReadStream) in node and pipe the stream to the response.